# Compiler error at use of assignment operator to copy an array in two classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I'm overloading assignment operator function to copy a char array to another char array in different objects. I can call the overloaded assignment operator function but not using assignment.

Can you please give me some guidance what I'm doing wrong? Can I use two classes using the assignment operator?

Thank you, Sergio

```
pTest = myData;//Fails

pTest->operator=(myData);//this works
```

```
struct Data {
char sourceName[5] = { 'S','o','l' };
};

class Test {
public:
//virtual void operator=(Data data) = 0;
void operator=(Data data);
void Show();
private:
char nameTest1[10];
};

void Test::operator=(Data data) {
strcpy_s(nameTest1, data.sourceName);
}

void Test::Show() {
cout << nameTest1;
}

int main() {
Test *pTest = new Test();
Data myData;
pTest = myData;//Fails
pTest->operator=(myData);//but this works
}
```

Expected result: array sourceName from data object is assigned to array nameTest1 in object Test.

Comment: Should be: `*pTest = myData;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pTest` is a pointer.

```
*pTest = myData;
```

should work.

Try and keep in mind that a pointer and what it points to are two different things. Both can be manipulated in C++ code, and so newbies often get them mixed up.

Comment: @SergioSolorzano Yep, we've all been there.

Comment: still someone thought it was appropriate to downvote my question, didn't link the issue because this worked pTest->operator=(myData); ...doh